# SubscribeOn main thread

Tags: java-8, rx-java, observable

How can I set the async operator of Observable to run in the main thread instead in another thread. Or at least set to get the result in the main thread once we finish.

```
    @Test
    public void retryWhen() {
        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newThread();
        Single.just("single")
                .map(word -> null)
                .map(Object::toString)
                .retryWhen(ot ->
                        ot.doOnNext(t -> System.out.println("Retry mechanism:" + t))
                                .filter(t -> t instanceof NullPointerException && cont < 5)
                                .flatMap(t -> Observable.timer(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,scheduler))
                                .doOnNext(t -> cont++)
                                .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(new NullPointerException())))
                .subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
//        new TestSubscriber()
//                .awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

I´m trying observerOn and subscribeOn but both are used to set in which thread you want the execution. But in my case I want the execution or the end of it in the same thread where I run the test

Right now the only way to see the prints are just blocking and waiting for the execution.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Observable.toBlocking()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toBlocking()) to get a [`BlockingObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html) and use that to extract your results in your tests.

Comment: Yes but that is just blocking, it´s pretty much the same than just wait for the other thread to finish. What I was looking was for a way to return the emitted item from another thread, into the main one. I think Subject  it´s one of my options. Thanks anyway

Comment: Do you need the results from the `Observable` before your `@Test` method ends? I don't see another way to that besides blocking.

Comment: The test it´s just a prove of concept to show what I want here. No worries I believe I got it already. I put you a positive for your help

Comment: Note that even if you use a subject, if the timer fires then the `onNext` will happen on that thread - you can't even build your own scheduler that passes data on the current thread (because that needs to be blocking on that thread, and that's what `toBlocking` does anyway...)

Comment: He could run an event loop on his main thread though, if that makes any sense. I don't know about his use case because he didn't describe it.

Comment: use a .test() operator to get a TestSubsriber/Observer and get the events from it. or else use a CountDownLatch to wait until the result arrives.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `observeOn`/`subscribeOn` and no operator or Observable changes the thread, then when you `subscribe` to the observable it will do all the processing *during the subscription*.

Comment: Yes, but Observable.timer is Async operator